# Conectar SQLServer 2014 con PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

Estoy intentando conectar SQLServer 2014 con PHP, al intentar este codigo funciona

```
$servidor = "NOMBREPC\SQLEXPRESS";
$database = "PRUEBA";
$info = array('Database'=>$database);
$cn = sqlsrv_connect($servidor, $info);
```

Pero al intentar usando una clase, no funciona

```
class Conexion{

    public function conectar(){

        $servidor = "NOMBREPC\SQLEXPRESS";
        $database = "PRUEBA";

        $info = array('Database'=>$database);
        $cn = sqlsrv_connect($servidor, $info);
        }
}
```

No se cual es el error, cabe resaltar que en el primer bloque de código use un if para saber si conectó, pero en el segundo al intentarlo no muestra el mensaje, también intente con el die().

Por favor ayúdenme. T.T

---

### **EDICION**

En el primer ejemplo si use el **sqlsrv_errors**, cuando cambiaba un valor que no era el correcto salian los errores, pero en el segundo puse un if, si conectaba tenia que salir *conectado* pero no sale nada, sale la pantalla en blanco. 
El codigo para llamar use el siguiente:

```
include ("Conexion.php");

class MiClase{
   public function miFuncion(){
      $cn = new Conexion;
      $cn->conectar();
   }
}
```

Todavía no logro conectar usando la clase.

Comment: ¿Has comprobado si te da algún error con [sqlsrv_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-errors.php)?

Comment: pon el código donde llamas a la función conectar

Comment: En el primer ejemplo si use el **sqlsrv_errors**, cuando cambiaba un valor que no era el correcto salian los errores, pero en el segundo puse un if, si conectaba tenia que salir _conectado_  pero no sale nada, sale la pantalla en blanco.

El codigo para  llamar use el siguiente:

`include ("Conexion.php");

class MiClase{

public function miFuncion(){
$cn = new Conexion;
$cn->conectar();
}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de varios intentos, logre realizar la conexión con SQL Server 2014, no se si el código que he usado es el correcto pero logró conectar.

```
   <?php

        class Conexion{

            private $cn;

            public function __construct(){
                $servidor = "NOMBRE-PC\SQLEXPRESS";
                $database = "BDPRUEBA";
                $info = array('Database'=>$database);
                $this->cn =sqlsrv_connect($servidor, $info);
            }

            public function getConecta(){
                return $this->cn;
            }

        }

?>
```

El llamado a la función es el siguiente:

```
<?php include ("Conexion.php");     

    class MiClase{      

        public function miFuncion(){

        $cn= new Conexion;

            $query = "SELECT * FROM demo";
            $registros = sqlsrv_query($cn->getConecta(), $query);
                if( $registros === false ){
                    echo "Error al ejecutar consulta.</br>";
                }  else {
                        while($demo= sqlsrv_fetch_array($registros)) {
                            $listado[] = $demo;                     
                        }
                        return $listado;
                }
        }       
    }

?>
```

Si hay algún error o hay una mejor forma de hacerlo por favor comunicarme. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser un problema con la autentificación del Server, de si se puede usar o no la validación de Windows.

Para los casos en los que le pasas tú el usuario, la contraseña y el puerto de conexión usa:

```
<?php
 $serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress, 1542"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (por defecto es 1433)
 $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
 $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

 if( $conn ) {
     echo "Conexión establecida.<br />";
 }else{
     echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
 }
 ?>
```

Tienes mas info [Aqui](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-connect.php)

Comment: Ahí sí funciona, el error es cuando intento hacerlo con una clase